# execute dynamic sql in datasnap client

Tags: delphi-xe2, datasnap

Is it possible to share database connection between datasnap server and client?

I want to execute dynamic sql in client and receive results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found 2 ways to execute dynamic sql in client side

1) Using DbxConnection (dbExpress)

```
// Server code
function TServerMethods1.GetConnection: TDbxConnection;
begin
  Result := DBConnection.DBXConnection;
end;


//Client code
dbxConnection := ServerMethods.GetConnection;
command := dbxConnection.CreateCommand;
command.Text := 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM clients WHERE name LIKE :name';
param := com.CreateParameter;
param.Name := 'name';
param.DataType := TDBXDataTypes.WideStringType;
param.Value.SetString('%name%');
command.Parameters.AddParameter(param);
reader := command.ExecuteQuery;
reader.Next; // to Fetch row
ShowMessage(reader.Value[0].AsString);
```

2) Using DataSet descendant

**Server side components**

ServerMethods class must be TDSServerModule descendant

- TConnection descendant
- TQuery descendant
- TDataSetProvider (set poAllowCommanedText to true)

**Client side components**

- TSqlConnection (for DataSnap connection)
- TDsProviderConnection (for DataSnap server methods)
- TClientDataSet (set provider)

code to execute query

```
CDS.Close; // TClientDataSet
CDS.CommandText := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE name LIKE :name';
CDS.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString := '%name%';
CDS.Open;
ShowMessage(CDS.Fields[0].AsString);
```

---

**Server side code:**

MainMethods.pas

```
TMainMethods = class(TDSServerModule)
  PgQuery: TPgQuery;
  PgQueryProvider: TDataSetProvider;
  PgConnection: TPgConnection;
end;
```

MainMethods.dfm

```
object MainMethods: TMainMethods
  Height = 248
  Width = 440
  object PgConnection: TPgConnection
    Left = 200
    Top = 32
    ...
  end
  object PgQuery: TPgQuery
    Connection: PgConnection
    Left = 32
    Top = 24
  end
  object PgQueryProvider: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = PgQuery
    Options = [poAllowCommandText, poUseQuoteChar]
    Left = 120
    Top = 24
  end
end
```

**Client side code:**

client.pas

```
TVerusClient = class(TDataModule)
  dbxVerusConnection: TSQLConnection;
  dbxSqlConnectionProvider: TDSProviderConnection;
  cdsSqlDataSet: TClientDataSet;
end;
```

client.dfm

```
object VerusClient: TVerusClient
  Height = 271
  Width = 415
  object dbxVerusConnection: TSQLConnection
    DriverName = 'DataSnap'
    LoginPrompt = False
    ...
  end
  object dbxSqlConnectionProvider: TDSProviderConnection
    ServerClassName = 'TMainMethods'
    SQLConnection = dbxVerusConnection
    Left = 176
    Top = 32
  end
  object cdsSqlDataSet: TClientDataSet
    ProviderName = 'PgQueryProvider'
    RemoteServer = dbxSqlConnectionProvider
    Left = 176
    Top = 104
  end
end
```

Comment: I think have not guessed at all.
I'm tring option 2, but no way to bind TClientDataSet with TDSProviderConnection.
Could you please expand that option code? Lotta thanks

Answer (score 0):

Main goal for DataSnap(Multi-Tier) application is security.You cannot share objects(connections,resources) directly(native) in remote mode but You can change SQL of Datasets on Session .  but it is not secure.

```
// Server Code
procedure TMyServerMethod.ChangeSQL(ASQL:string); // insecure
begin
  AdoQuery1.Active:=false;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text:=ASQL; // AdoQuery,DbxExpress,UniDAC,AnyDac,...    
  AdoQuery1.Active:=true;
end;
```

use [generate proxy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generating_DataSnap_Server_Method_Proxies)  for client side

```
// Client Code
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject);
begin
  Proxy.ChangeSQL('select * from custom_table');// but it is insecure
  // loading remote datasets
end;
```

Comment: I know, that is not secure, but I'm trying to convert more than 15 years old actively developed 2-tier application to 3-tier and without rewriting entire application it seems only feasible solution