# Can I use dynamically created SQL with DataSnap?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap

Is it necessary to define the queries (with methods) in the server so that the client can access them?

Or can I create queries "on demand" on the client system to access data from the DataSnap server ?

Comment: Have you checked their [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application)?

Comment: in multi-tier application I must access to database indirectly.for example define a function that Select All Records of `tbl1`.sending(directly) sql command  to application server is harmful

Comment: You do not want your clients to connect to your database, that is why you use a server application(Datasnap) to make the connection for you, and hide the database from your client. You open a dataset on your datasnap server. Then send the data with a datasetprovider that the client can acces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example you can set the CommandText property of a TClientDataSet - which is connected to the server - dynamically:

```
  CDS.Close;
  CDS.CommandText := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE name LIKE :name';
  CDS.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString := '%name%';
  CDS.Open;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685852/80901) shows other options.